# Laying out radio buttons and text area in a dialog

Tags: gui-design, buttons, layout, dialog

I have a dialog where I need to lay out radio buttons and their corresponding text and icons, and a text area. This is my current dialog layout, where the colors denote the icons. Note that the last item doesn't have an icon.

The dialog is to be used in a desktop app. The purpose of it is to type-ify the selected item. I chose radio buttons because drop-down would result in an extra click. The last item clears the type from the item, hence no icon (maybe I should add one?).

Is this the best this kind of widgets can be laid out? Any other options you'd recommend?

[image]

Comment: Can you specify the context of this dialog box, better? What comes before, and what comes after? Also, any specific reason why you have radio boxes, but not a dropdown to select a value? What is the significance of the icons that you have used? Why the last item does not have an icon? What is the use case? Will this be for a mobile interface? A tablet interface? A web interface? Those are a lot of questions. :) But if you can specify the details of your question, in a detailed manner, it'll be easier for other's to give you a productive answer/views.

Comment: The dialog is to be used in a desktop app. The purpose of it is to type-ify the selected item. I chose radio buttons because drop-down would result in an extra click. The last item clears the type from the item, hence no icon (maybe I should add one?).

Comment: Thanks. Can you add the whole description as part of your question, by editing your question?

Comment: Okay, I've updated the original post

Answer (score 1):

One radio button that clear selection in the others, Type 6, is quite misleading. If you want to clear, do that as a separate button, not radio button.

If you allow users to keep the whole radio button group unselected, then it may be not clear why you suggest user to select one. I think user first decides "do I need A or B?" and this radio group is relevant only for one of choices. That's why I'd suggest following:

1. First a radio group of 2 buttons (or a check box), where user decides something thing.
2. Based on selection in the 1st question you enable or disable the radio group of 5 elements. Then you don't need clearing of selected radio button. If user selected particular answer in the 1st question, he *must* select one of values in the radio group of 5 buttons.

```
    Do you prefer A or B?
    (x) Prefer A      ( ) Prefer B

    If A peferred:
    ( ) Type1   ( ) Type4
    ( ) Type2   ( ) Type5
    ( ) Type3
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- Lay out radio buttons vertically because horizontal layouts make it hard to tell which option belongs to which button.
- Consider adding a "None of the above" option.
- If you have too many options and not enough space, try a dropdown menu.

For reference: https://designsystem.digital.gov/components/radio-buttons/